# Mysql installer not configuring mysql

Tags: mysql

So I have recently tried to install Mysql from the MySQL installer from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html
so when I opened up the installer, I followed the instructions, until I came up with something that said I didn't have python. According to multiple youtube tutorials, I just had to skip that bit. Also, in the tutorials, the YouTubers came across a page where they configure the installer, but I didn't come across that page, and now my databases can't connect. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, or making new databases, but still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the 'mysql installer community' (the second one) rather than 'mysql installer web community' (the first one). It will take a bit longer to download, but it fixes the problem.

Comment: Okay.          (ignore this bit cus stackoverflow only allows 15 character long comments)

Comment: Wow it works! I know stackoverflow says don't just comment thanks, but I'm doing so anyway :D